# Regex noob needing a pattern to match specific string patterns

Tags: php, regex

Hi I'm trying to match a search string so that if there is us zipcode is at the beginning of the string, return the matches of the zipcode as well as the rest of the string. This is what i have so far

```
$str = "90210 Beverly Hills, CA";
$res = preg_match('/^((\d{5})(-\d{4})?)\s+(.+?)$/', $str, $matches);
```

But when I print_r the matches it returns with an extra key for the space.

```
Array
(
    [0] => 90210 Beverly Hills, CA
    [1] => 90210
    [2] => 90210
    [3] =>
    [4] => Beverly Hills, CA
)
```

Is there anyway i can improve the pattern and return matches which is not an empty string? Is there a better pattern for this instance? Also if just a zipcode is given or just a text string, it would return false.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is *no*.  A visual inspection of your pattern parentheses indicates that the fourth match would be the -1234 (four extra zip digits -- no idea what they're formally called), and in your example, that is empty.  It is a bit unclear from your question what you want to actually capture.  I will leave with a construct you may find useful:

```
(?: ...)
```

If you have `?:` after a paren, it indicates that a capture should not be made.  You can add this before the "dash-four-digit" subpattern and it will not be added to `matches`.

Comment: Well i'm looking for a pattern so if there is a zipcode at the start of the string and its followed by text, return the both the zipcode and the text as matches. If it does not fit these conditions (e.g. just "90210" or just "Beverly Hills, CA" or "Beverly Hills, CA 90210") it will return no matches

Comment: Oh .. your original expression looks fine, just use `matches[0]`, which is the entire match.  If you don't want to capture a sub-pattern, use `?:`, but it makes no difference since the zeroth match should always be what you want (well `?:` will be faster, but so little that you won't notice unless you're inspecting millions of zip code lines)

Answer (score 0):

```
^((\d{5})?(.*+))$
```

http://rubular.com/r/bZJe4p1k9O

Answer (score 0):

Your match group 3 is not a space. It is empty (or perhaps undefined or something - I'm not deeply involved with PHP). The empty value represents that there was no match to the optional group `(-\d{4})` (US ZIP+4). I imagine you will want to keep your expression as it is so that you can easily detect the case that no ZIP+4 is present.